# Is it possible to have an associated type synonym with variables not mentioned in the type class?

Tags: haskell, types

In *[Associated Type Synonyms](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/CKP05.html)* (Chakravarty, Keller, Jones) the paper seems to indicate that the following is valid:

```
class C a where
  type S a (k :: * -> *) :: *
```

However, when I try and run this I get a compiler error (with `-XTypeFamilies`):

```
Not in scope: type variable `k'
```

Am I missing anything, or is the actual implementation in GHC not the same as what is mentioned in the paper?

Comment: I've now found http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3714 which to me reads as though this can't be done. If this is correct, please feel free to answer with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out, [this is not possible in GHC](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Associated_family_declarations_2):

> Exactly as in the case of an associated data declaration, **the named type parameters must be a permutation of a subset of the class parameters**. Examples
>
> ```
> class C a b c where { type T c a :: * }   -- OK
> class D a where { type T a x :: * }       -- No: x is not a class parameter
> class D a where { type T a :: * -> * }    -- OK
> ```

The ticket you referred to actually explains the reason for not being able to define something like `S`. It works if you do it like this:

```
class C a where
    type S a :: (* -> *) -> *
data TupK a k = TupK (a, k a)
instance C [a] where
    type S [a] = TupK a
```

However, now you're stuck with a new data type. Using type synonyms won't work ("Type synonym `TupK' should have 2 arguments"), and adding more parameters to `S` won't help ("Number of parameters must match family declaration; expected 1"), as documented in the ticket.

Comment: @ocharles I would add that you don't *have* to use an *associated* type. You could perfectly well do something like `type family S a (k :: * -> *); class C a where foo :: S a [] -> Int`. The main advantage of associated types is that it makes it easier for the compiler to give good error messages (and a more convenient syntax for declaring type instances).

Comment: Yes, for now I have separated the 2, but it was nice to have them paired

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can do the less powerful:

```
class C a where
  type S a :: (k :: * -> *) -> *
```

... which could serve the same purpose if you don't need the additional power.