# Equality constraints in Constraint kinds

Tags: haskell, types, type-kinds

My question is about how to put an equality constraint in an associated type constraint (i.e. type of kind Constraint)

The specific use case is a class parameterized by a partially applied type:

```
class Foo c where -- c has kind *->*->*
  type Ctx c m r :: Constraint
  f :: (Ctx c m r) => c m r -> c m r
```

In a particular instance, I would like to write:

```
data Bar m r = ...

instance Foo Bar where
   type Ctx Bar m r = (m~Maybe b) 
   -- m must be a Maybe, I don't care what its parameter is
   f = ...
```

However, GHC complains: 'Not in scope: type variable b'.
I don't see any other way to express this constraint. Not every instance requires that 'm~Maybe b', so I cannot move this constraint to the type signature of f.  b is not in scope in the instance anywhere (perhaps this is what GHC is complaining about), but there is no need for it to be. The function

```
f :: (a ~ Maybe b) => a -> a -> a
```

is valid, I see no reason why I can't do this with Constraints. This problem occurs with top-level constraints, as well as with associated type constraints.

Possibly related is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622840/equality-on-constraints?rq=1) question, except I need equality with a variable NOT in scope.

Comment: You could try `type Ctx Bar m r = forall b. a ~ Maybe b` (this requires the `Rank2Types` and `LiberalTypeSynonyms` language extensions).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113980/is-it-possible-to-have-an-associated-type-synonym-with-variables-not-mentioned-i?rq=1)

Comment: @is7s But GHC *does* support that now... and this question is about a completely different aspect anyway.

Comment: @DanielWagner isn't the problem here that the type variable `b` is not a class parameter? If so, isn't this the same problem of the other question? Am I missing something?

Comment: @is7s No, that is not the problem: the problem is that constraints can't quantify over types. Associated type families can perfectly well have non-class-parameter arguments these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way to express this constraint:

```
class IsMaybe m {- where ...whatever operations you need to do on Maybe values -}
instance IsMaybe (Maybe b) {- where ...implement those operations -}
instance Foo Bar where
    type Ctx Bar m r = IsMaybe m
```

However, given Haskell naming conventions, I would be kind of surprised if this is actually what you want -- is `m` really a type variable of kind `*` and not of kind `* -> *`? In case it's the latter, you'd just want

```
instance Foo Bar where
    type Ctx Bar m r = m~Maybe
```

...and possibly a kind annotation in the class declaration for `Foo`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'll give this a shot. m is in fact a (crazy) user-defined type of kind *->*. I'm still wondering if what I tried in my question should be legal, or if perhaps it just isn't implemented yet.